# SceneKit repeat texture

Tags: objective-c, scenekit

For some reason, using the following material on an SCNBox keeps resulting in a stretched texture. Any idea where I'm missing something?

```
material.diffuse.contents = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"arrowtexture.jpg"];
material.diffuse.wrapS = SCNWrapModeRepeat;
material.diffuse.wrapT = SCNWrapModeRepeat;
```

Comment: The `SCNWrapModeRepeat` will only start to have an effect if your texture coordinates exceed the range 0 to 1. Say if you had a box, and one of its faces had a texture coordinate of 0,0 at one corner and 10,10 at the other corner. In this case you'd see your texture repeated 100x across the box face. The default texture coordinated for an `SCNBox` are within the range 0-1. The [`contentsTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395388-contentstransform) property would let you change these default texture coords.

Comment: Thanks, that's the bit of info I needed, guess I overlooked it in the Apple docs :-).

Answer (score 0):

You can control `SKTexture`'s stretch this way:

```
material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(3, 1, 1);
```

Comment: But why it's 3?

Comment: For example 3, for x-axis compression.

Comment: :-) I was thinking it's some magic number.

Comment: Does that work for you?